# Link Minecraft ban reason to Discord.js

Tags: discord.js, minecraft

Ok, so, I know this sounds impossible, but I have coded an ID generator in Discord.js and was wondering if I could link this code to my minecraft server to show as a Ban ID for players to appeal for their ban.
My ID code:

```
    var ID = function () {
        return '#' + Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 9);
    };
    var banID = ID();
    var o = { 'public': 'foo' };
    o[banID] = 'bar';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do, but you could use the spigot/bukkit/paper plugin DiscordSRV's console feature to execute commands using the bot. There's more info [here](https://www.spigotmc.org/resources/discordsrv.18494/) and [here](https://github.com/DiscordSRV/DiscordSRV/wiki).